# ML - Service Desk classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to explore an use-case in ML but stuck at a point. May i please request your advise please.

Have a service desk web application for logging tickets, which is essentially a form having various fields like -

```
subject,
content, 
username, 
emailid,
category - {hardware, application, datafix, mobileapp, etc.}, 
service group - {AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, etc.}, 
domain - {email, walkin, phonecall, etc.},
priority - {high, medium, low}
#(Apologies for the poor quality of sample data provided above.)
```

Based on this info, the ticket is then manually assigned to respective team owners for resolution.

My intent is to use ML - based on the above fields, predict the Team who will work on this ticket. (Team ex. HR or IT or Desktop support or Pantry or Facilities, etc. )

1. Can this use-case be categorized as Multi-class classification
   problem?
2. The field values are stored as words in database. How can it be fed
   to my ML as numbers?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the DataScience Stack exchange.

Since your target variable has many categories your problem is Multi class classification. On how to implement and find a solution for this problem you can find on google. The following 2 links are for reference:

1. [Link-1](https://www.codementor.io/agarrahul01/multiclass-classification-using-random-forest-on-scikit-learn-library-hkk4lwawu)
2. [Link-2](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-12f1e60e0a9f)

Here I'm not giving much information on which algorithm to use. If you need any additional help you can raise one more question so that we can help you better as we don't now much about your data and business problem.

So, to answer your question 2, you can convert them into number it is one line [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers),I've added the link for your reference.

Please let us know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Much appreciated. I'll go through it and revert if any doubts. I've done some practice hands-on with ML+Py, now undergoing a real use-case. :)

Comment: Your link-2 was really useful and exactly mentions what I was looking for. Many thanks. It covers aspects of - Text representation (using Bag-of-words and TFIDF), and n-grams to understand the correlation among the words.

Comment: That is great! All the best!

Comment: Post training and validation once a model is selected and deployed into practice, does it consider (learn from) further incoming data and keep itself maturing?

Comment: Generally it depends on the model, for instance if we are talking about random forest then you have to train the mode periodically to improve itself like once in a week or month based on the severity.

Comment: That's good to know. So, first I will start with a dataset of 300 observations, and try various models to see the prediction score. Once I get something satisfactory, I'll try to ingest more observations (say ~2000 observations) and test. And go on... Does this approach look right?

Comment: That is now the right procedure, using lesser sample won’t change it using a target variable with less levels could increase your accuracy.

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: Training in batches wouldn’t change anything but you loosing information and cannot build a robust model. Instead of that you can use the target variable with less level(less categories) so you can build a robust model.

Comment: You have been very helpful, Toros. What you taught will never be found in any books, but real experience. Appreciate it. I'm sure other newbie ML tinkerers will find these conversation useful later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It really made me happy, I’m happy that I’m helpful.

Comment: But why do you think having less categories will make a robust model, and changing sample size will be detrimental ("loosing information") ?

Comment: For instance the whole data is 1000 records and target variable has 3 categories all of them are 333,334,333. if you have taken a sample of it 300 in total and in that category one is 200,50 and 50 of category 2 and 3. Now when you train the model it will be good at classifying category 1 but not 2 and 3 because your model doesn’t have enough data to perform well. But if you look at the whole dataset all 3 classes are balanced. So sampling overs is very important and should be done carefully.

Comment: Now I see. Great point noted. I've tried to get a decent distribution of various categories though in my sample data.