# Feature matrix for email classification:

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, nltk

This is in continuation of my earlier [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/43911/ml-service-desk-classification).

In my previous model, I used just two features which couldn't fare well and gave 71% prediction (accuracy) score. Now, I'm trying to consider another important field "subject" from the data set. I'm planning to use NLTK package along with Tf-Idf.

I generated the below using NLTK (*FreqDist*) on the subject field - 
[image]
Here is my idea:
I'll tokenize the subject field, apply stopwords, then Tf-Idf and get the top N *most frequent* words and use them as features. The Tf-Idf score will be my values. In total, I'll have (N+2) features.

But, one downside is - the feature matrix will be huge (say 200+ features) and sparse. Is that a concern? Does this design make sense?

Your thoughts please.